# Vaadin : is it possible to build for production a vaadin application without NodeJS?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm currently developing a vaadin application. I need to build it in order to push it to production.
Nevertheless, I noticed that npm is required in order to build.
Is it possible to build the application without the use of npm ? (company restrictions)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have already answered you own question. If NPM is required, it's required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can upgrade to Vaadin 24.1 and you are not using anything that requires custom front-end bundle (like Polymer/LitTemplates & certain add-ons), npm is not needed. With versions from 10 to 24.0 npm is needed (installed by Vaadin tooling if not found) for production build.

Comment: Do you have a custom theme maybe? That seemed to trigger npm build for me on one app.